# Java. Браузер без отображения контента для загрузки на стороне сервера

Tags: java, сервер, webbrowser

Не знаю как лучше вопрос назвать. Идея простая (пока что просто балуюсь конечно), иногда хочется связать свой сервер с уже существующими сторонними сайтами. Иногда просто распарсить выдачу, иногда чего то посложнее сделать, например связать с аккаунтом пользователя.

Но вот бывает всё это дело в сторонних сайтах опирается на связанные сервисы, иногда просто дополнительные запросы для безопасности, иногда на JS код. Так может кто-то знает какую нибудь библиотеку, которая позволяет, прогрузить страницу, сделать редиректы, прогрузить всё внутри, кроме картинок и стилей (или дать возможность вручную это делать, иногда под картинку и запрос прячут) и по желанию выполнить JS? В принципе без исполнения JS можно и свой велик сделать быстро. А из готового только WebView из JavaFX приходит в голову. Но я даже боюсь представить, сколько ресурсов будет такой компонент кушать.

Comment: Без JS -- Jsoup, с JS -- Selenium.

Comment: вместо Selenium рекомендую PhanromJS

Comment: Не совсем ясен вопрос. Вы хотите загрузить исходные коды страницы на локальный жесткий диск? Может быть вам нужен wget?